# group_by not returning all levels in grouped variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having some problems with group_by. I know that my grouping variabel has two levels, but group_by only returns one of them.

What am I doing wrong?

y is my grouping variabel with two levels, but the command returns this output with only one line:

```
  mean Q10 Q50 Q90
  1 16.5 1.1 7.5  49
```

Below code recreates the problem.

```
#A dataset:
v <- c(1,2,3,4,5,10,20,30,40,50)
y <- rep(0:1, each = 5)
a <- as.data.frame.matrix(cbind(v,y))

#The group_by command that doesn't work    
a %>% group_by(y) %>% summarize(mean = mean(v), 
                                    Q10 = quantile(v, 0.1, type=6),
                                    Q50 = quantile(v, 0.5, type=6),
                                    Q90 = quantile(v, 0.9, type=6))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have probably loaded `plyr` after `dplyr` so it is using the wrong `summarize`.

```
a %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  plyr::summarize(mean = mean(v), 
            Q10 = quantile(v, 0.1, type=6),
            Q50 = quantile(v, 0.5, type=6),
            Q90 = quantile(v, 0.9, type=6))
#   mean Q10 Q50 Q90
# 1 16.5 1.1 7.5  49

a %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  dplyr::summarize(mean = mean(v), 
            Q10 = quantile(v, 0.1, type=6),
            Q50 = quantile(v, 0.5, type=6),
            Q90 = quantile(v, 0.9, type=6))
# # A tibble: 2 x 5
#       y  mean   Q10   Q50   Q90
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     0     3     1     3     5
# 2     1    30    10    30    50
```

Comment: You  are right - I just realized that, and came  here to delete the question. Thank you for replying.